# How to correctly format API requests for Mandrill using Fetch plugin? Getting error "you must specify a key value"

Tags: templating, craft3, mandrill, api

I want to use the Fetch plugin (v 1.2.0; Craft Pro 3.3.13) to send messages from a Twig template in some circumstances.

To test the setup, I'm just trying to ping Mandrill, according to the /users/ping.json call: https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/users.JSON.html#method=ping.

I've tried a bunch of variations, but I keep getting this error:

```
1 - Server error: 
`GET https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/users/ping.json` 
resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response:
{
  "status":"error",
  "code":-1,
  "name":"ValidationError",
  "message":"You must specify a key value"
}
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17700002/mandrill-validationerror) (admittedly from 2013), "This particular error is common if the JSON is invalid for some reason."

I've looked at [Jalen's excellent answer on another Fetch question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/29630/fetching-displaying-an-api-request-using-fetch), but that's for a different API and I'm not sure what to do.

Here's my current code:

```
      {% set client = {
          base_uri : 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/',
          timeout : 10
        } %}


        {% set options = {
          key: 'REDACTED',
        } %}

        {% set destination = 'users/ping.json' %}

        {% set request = fetch(client, 'GET', destination, options) %}
```

I've also tried it with POST, and with various permutations of quotes around the key and api key; same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things I'm noticing about your code snippet:

1. You'll want to use `POST` per the [Mandrill API docs](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/index.JSON.html).

   > All API calls should be made with HTTP POST.
2. The options object should only contain [valid Guzzle request options](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html) (`key` is not an actual request option); I think what you're trying to do is pass your `key` parameter in the request body. There are multiple options for sending data in the request body (`form_params`, `body`, `json`, or `multipart`), but since the Mandrill API is expecting a json request body we'll use the `json` option like so:

   ```
   {% set options = {
     json: {
       key: 'REDACTED',
     }
   } %}
   ```

---

All together, this should give you a working API call:

```
{% set client = {
  base_uri: 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/',
  timeout: 10
} %}


{% set options = {
  json: {
    key: 'REDACTED',
  }
} %}

{% set destination = 'users/ping.json' %}

{% set request = fetch(client, 'POST', destination, options) %}
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much.